# How to delete certain Cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I would like to delete certain cells if an adjacent cell does not have a value (empty). Can anyone write a VBA code for it ?

For example: if cell “C” in any given row is empty then delete Cell “A” in the same row.

Thanks…

Comment: Welcome to Super User. New members commonly mistake this for a service site where we will do the work. It is a Q&A community where specific questions are asked after you have attempted something and get stuck. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including scripts, code or formulas, and we will try to help. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Answer (score 0):

If we start with data like:

[image]

and run this short macro:

```
Sub KleanUpA()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Range("C:C").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Offset(0, -2)
    r.Clear
End Sub
```

we will get:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this code is not working in my Excel: I have two versions of excels for Mac. 2010 and 2016 and neither of them is woking with this code. Usually, VBA codes are universal for Mac or Windows. What could be wrong with the code?

Comment: @igorf.  Are you getting an error message ??

Comment: No, after I posted the VBA code. Nothing is happening. After I clear/delete cells in column "C" nothing is happening at all. No error messages. I tried to save and close the workbook and then reopen but nothing is working.